# How do I create a sine wave signal in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am a noob programmer who just started learning about Cocoa.

I want to create a sine wave signal interface. How can I do that?

I saw that someone used code from [this processing example](http://www.processing.org/learning/library/sinewavesignal.html)  to create one.  How can I do something similar in my application?

Comment: Xcode is the IDE, not a language or a library. So the answer depends on the language(C/C++/Objective-C/Java/...), framework-library(Cocoa/CocoaTouch/...), platform(MacOS/iOS), etc Please be more specific

Comment: owh sorry.. actually any language would do as long as the language supported by xcode.. (objective c/c++/c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest you to refer [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application from Apple .
Also you can refer to [Coreplot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) framework.

Comment: @shy, if you think the answer helps you to solve your problem then select the checkmark against it & vote it up.

Comment: i already checkmark it but cannot vote yet i havent register.. later after i register will do that..